# Constructor Issues - Won't display different results for text and value

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor

I am trying to get the values and text of a dropdown menu to display different variations of the same data. The date in the value needs to be more machine readable but the text needs to be more human friendly. Currently I have this:

```
dateItems.Add(new ListItem(date.ToString("ddd, dd-MM-yyyy"), date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
    }
    recordDate.DataSource = dateItems;
    recordDate.DataBind();
```

but the end result is that both the text and the value of the dropdown list are showing only the text part of the code:

```
<option value="Sat, 16-09-2017">Sat, 16-09-2017</option>
```

I just don't get why they are the same when the alternate text for value exists.

Any ideas as to what I've done to break this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace

```
recordDate.DataSource = dateItems
recordDate.DataBind()
```

to

```
recordDate.DataValueField = "Value"
recordDate.DataTextField = "Text"
recordDate.DataSource = dateItems
recordDate.DataBind()
```

Comment: OMG! Something so easy... Than you so much. Works perfect `<option value="2017-09-16">Sat, 16-09-2017</option>` :-)